# How I may retrieve value from mutableStateMapOf() in fragment?

Tags: kotlin, generics, mvvm, retrofit

I've been following some tutorial about wrapping retrofit with generics. Everything is working, I can log value from ViewModel, but I can't `collect` it, or `observe`. How I may retrieve the data then?

**ViewModel**

`var someVar: HashMap<String, Float> by mutableStateMapOf()`

`...`

```
fun fetchData(q: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                when (val myResponse =
                    repo.getData(q)) {
                    is RetrofitState.Success -> {
                        someVar = response._data?.DataFromApi!!
                    }
                    is RetrofitState.Error -> {
                        TODO()
                    }
                }
            } catch (exception: exception) {
                Log.i(
                    TAG,
                    "error"
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to collect or observe. You simply use the `someVar` in your Composable like a normal property. Since it is State, your Composable will automatically recompose when the data changes and get the latest data. If you aren't using Compose for your UI, then you shouldn't be using `mutableStateMapOf`.

Comment: Thank you. I've chaned it to LiveData.